# Non-continuous range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I like to calculate my investment return using XIRR. However, this only works if I have sold my investment. I thus calculate XIRR by assuming I have sold the investment today.

Because the cash flow and current investment are in different sheet, I tried to use Non-continuous range but it does not work.

Question: May I know if there is an alternative approach? Javascript solution is fine too.

```
=xirr({ARRAYFORMULA((B2:B5="IBM")*C2:C5),A8},{ARRAYFORMULA( (B2:B5="IBM")*A2:A5),C8})

Column A: transaction date
Column B: Stock symbol. I use IBM as an example
Column C: Cash flow

Row 8 is the current value
```

The formula works if I did not include A8 and C8 but that also excludes the current market value, which is not want I want.

Comment: Not sure why this was voted down. I tried various ways to solve it before coming here.  I noted Google Sheet accept non-continual array like {A1,A2,A3,A10} but not {A1:A3,A10}. Is there a way to sidestep the issue using ARRAYFORMULA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since non-continual range notation does not work, I wrote a function to merger the ranges.

```
{A1:A3,A10} does not work.  Do I do 
MR(A1:A3,A10) 

function MR(r,c=[]){
  var result=r; 
  if (c.constructor==Array){
    c.forEach((f)=>{
      result.push(f);
    });
  }else{
    result.push(c)
  }
  return result;
}
```

my final formualar for row 29:

```
=xirr(filter(MR(Transections!R:R,$O$2:$O),MR(Transections!C:C,$B$2:$B)=B29),filter(MR(Transections!A:A,$Y$2:$Y),MR(Transections!C:C,$B$2:$B)=B29))

For the active sheet
column O: The current market value of the stock.
column B: The stock code
column Y: Current date. XIRR does not accept Now() so need to type in current date.

On the Transections sheet:
Column R: Cash flow from buy/sell
Column C: Stock code
Column A: Transections date.
```

Do let me know if there is an easier way.